# cocos2d-x for android, crash with string concatenation

Tags: string, concatenation, cocos2d-x

On Cocos2d-x v3 this code:

```
string _nameImgBase="pedina";
string nameImg=_nameImgBase+"B.png";
auto img=Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName(nameImg);
```

compiles without errors, but on Android crash the application.
The strange thing is that if I compile the same code on XCode for iPhone ... then there are no problems, everything is working.
Why?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not present in the "SpriteFrameCache",but if you want to add a simple sprite from your resources folder you simply use

```
auto img=Sprite::create(nameImg);
```

Comment: the image is present, if I call auto img=Sprite::create("pedina0B.png"); the app work, but if I call auto img=Sprite::create(nameImg); the app crash! I think the problem is string concatenation but I don't know ...

Comment: -you are writing "pedina0B.png" not "pedinaB.png" ("pedina"+"B.png" in your code)
-if the problem still persists use 'std::to_string'